# Interviewing for consulting position involves interview with customer; is this unusual?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, consulting

I am going through the interview process with a consulting company X for a senior consultant position.  We have had 2 phone and 1 in person interview and they have indicated that they are interested in hiring me but have not yet made an offer.

This week, I have a 4th phone interview with a potential customer of company X which I am led to believer is the last step of the process.

I am a little put off by the interview with the customer as I would expect that company X should be able to make their own determination of my skills/experience match for the role and base their decision off of that.  Likewise, it seems like having another party involved with veto power doesn't work in my favor.

It's also a bit strange that prior to this phone interview with the customer, they have converted my resume to their company's format (without consulting me) and sent it to their customer.

Am I overreacting here or is this process unusual and potentially a little unethical?  They are essentially leveraging my portfolio to sell a service agreement that they don't yet have personnel for and conditioning my hiring on it's success.  I can see it from their perspective too, but it does rub me the wrong way.

Otherwise it seems like a good company to work for with some really bright and talented people.

Comment: How do you know they converted and sent your CV to this customer?

Comment: it was attached to the meeting invite.  Plus they told me that's what they did.

Comment: One man's survey result:  (1) yes, it seems incredibly annoying and silly.  they need to get off the fence.  (2) I would probably suck it up and talk to the client, which may be interesting anyway  :/

Comment: It really depends on the structure of the consulting firm's work and their arrangement with the client. One of my consulting firms did this regularly. If the consulting firm is naturally closer to a staffing agency, this is pretty common: you're basically working for the client, so it's natural for them to play a role in your selection.

Comment: It's a good point that if it's more of "an agency" - it's pretty normal.

Comment: There is a good and accepted answer already but I wanted to add something from my experiences.  The consulting firm thinks you are a great enough candidate to show you to one of their clients.. That is a promising sign right there so follow it through to the end.  I was in this exact process many years ago and at the time i got "we really like you but the client chose someone else so there is no job".. I professionally thanked them for the chance... A year later they called me out of the blue with a different client willing to pay more.. No interview needed the second time

Comment: I'm a consultant and the last interview I had was with the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I overreacting here or is this process unusual and potentially a little unethical?

IMO, this doesn't seem unusual to me.

If this is a consulting position, it makes sense that the company the consulting service is being provided to should have a say on which person(s) they would like for this specific project.

This makes sense because the consulting company is providing a *service* to this third-party company, one that is specific and customized for this project. Thus, they are filtering which current and prospect employees are best fit for this project.

Anyways, it is still recommended that you keep your options open until you receive and accept an offer, and apply to other prospect jobs you have in mind.

Answer (score 4):

> I am a little put off by the interview with the customer as I would
>   expect that company X should be able to make their own determination
>   of my skills/experience match for the role and base their decision off
>   of that. Likewise, it seems like having another party involved with
>   veto power doesn't work in my favor.

Some customers require veto power over people being added to their contract. I have had to do this several times. In some cases I was a new hire, in other cases a already worked for the company but they wanted to add me to an existing contract.

There are several reasons why they require this step: the customer has been burned by unqualified people; the contracting company has burned customers by assigning unqualified people.

Some customers have gone a step further by requiring a resume check by a third party company.

> It's also a bit strange that prior to this phone interview with the
>   customer, they have converted my resume to their company's format
>   (without consulting me) and sent it to their customer.

Once you do become an employee this is a normal event in most companies.

Answer (score 1):

Recruiting, consulting, and staffing companies do this routinely and I don't see this as abnormal or unusual. You've interviewed with the company performing the search and now you're interviewing with the "end user client". Both are necessary. Your interviews with the company performing the search are meant to validate that you fit what the end user client is looking for and to weed out people who aren't fit. Since you will ultimately be working for the end user client they naturally want to interview you as well. Nothing irregular about that.

As for your resume, what do you care what they do with it? You gave it to them. Their copy of your resume belongs to them to do with as they please. Reformat it, burn it, throw it away, etc. I'm failing to see why this would upset you. It's a piece of paper. Nothing more.